# MySQL query for parent and child table

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a mysql query. I have two tables, one parent, one child.

Parent table: `garments`

```
  `garment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`garment_id`)
```

Child table: `garment_images`

```
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `garment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I would like query all garments, and to show the first image for each item from the 'garment_images' table.

Comment: Ya great, did you tried anything first?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please read this article: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Nope, couldn't think how to even get this started, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first image"?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly close:

```
SELECT G.*, (
    SELECT GI.id, GI.filename from garment_images as GI
       WHERE GI.garment_id = G.garment_id
       ORDER BY GI.order DESC
       LIMIT 1)
FROM garments as G
```

Comment: You can't have 2 columns in an inline subquery: `SELECT GI.id, GI.filename`

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem:

1. Retreive the first image id for every garment
2. Put the data together

**Step 1:**

```
select gi.*
from 
    garment_images as gi
    inner join (
        select min(id) as minId 
        from garment_images 
        group by garment_id
    ) as a on gi.garment_id = a.minId
```

I'll leave to you the second step (Hint: join the data from the query above with your garment table)

Answer (score 0):

If "the first image" is the one with `order = 1`   [(SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4002/1)

```
SELECT * from garments g JOIN garment_images gi 
  ON g.garment_id = gi.garment_id
  WHERE gi.order = 1
```